# Why does my node.js app crash when trying to use JSON.parse(data) on incoming data from youtube api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, youtube-api, get-request

I am trying to use the youtube api to search for videos using a simple front-end with a search box and search button.

I am using the standard https.get() method to achieve this.
The problem I am having, is that once that data arrives inside the response.on() block of code, I would normally use JSON.parse on that data, and store in inside another variable where I would have usable javascript object.

the result is the app crashing with this error in the console:
`undefined:25 "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fWRISvAygU/ SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>`
and the standard `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

What I can confirm is the following:

-I have tried getting that data in postman (the EXACT same url pasted into postman), and I do receive a long json format as usual

-I have confirmed that the data I am getting from my front-end is translating into strings that fit nicely into the url
-I have console logged the status code inside the https.get() method, and I get a 200ok

-I have console logged the (data) that is inside the response.on("data", function(data){})
without parsing it yet, and I get buffer data `<Buffer 7d 0a 20 20 22 6b .... bla bla`

NOTE: I do have to note something important: I have only done this with one project before (getting weather data from a weather API) and in the code from my other project, which worked perfectly,the only difference I see, is that the buffer data I am getting before JSON.parse() is applied to the incoming data, that buffer data had only one sequence. which means it was a one shot `<Buffer 7d 0a 20 20 22 6b bla bla more bytes>`
the current data I am trying to retrieve in my current project is coming in 5 different chunks of buffer data. I can see 5 different opening and closing tags of that buffer data when I am console logging the data before I try to JSON.parse().

Forgive me if I am not using great terminology here, as this is my 6th month of coding, and I am still early in this journey. I have just started dabbling with APIs with Node.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const Joi = require("joi");
const apiKey = "MyKeyWouldBeHere"; (hiding it)

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));





app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

app.post("/videos", (req, res) => {
    const {error} = validation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send("wrong way to write");

    
    const userInput = req.body.userInput;

    https.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=${apiKey}&q=${userInput}`, (response) => {
        
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data", function(data) {
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);

        });
    });


});


app.listen("3000", () => {
    console.log("Running server on port 3000");
});


function validation(value) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        userInput: Joi.string().min(2).required()
    });
    return schema.validate(value);
}
```

Comment: Please google how to query data using `https.get` you should parse the data when it's complete

Comment: Hi Konrad, I appreciate your response. This is actually what confuses me, because isn't that what I was trying to do? by writing JSON.parse(data) and passing the data that is received in the response.on("data" (data) => {const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)}) This is what understand from research on the web regarding making https.get requests. I see everyone using JSON.parse(data). For some reason, it works perfectly fine if I switch the api with another one

Comment: `data` event can fire multiple times if the response is big and comes in chunks. You should collect the entire data and then parse

Comment: Ok that's great, I did not know that. I learned something! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, visibly, Javascript don't like 'data', for me i just had to change the var to reponseText and everything is good now.

Will never know

Comment: Hi, maybe it’s `responseText`, and not reponseText. If someone does a copy and paste of your answer, gets new errors